# New Intent wont start first time

Tags: java, android

I have 3 intents
A->B->C

from C to get back to A you bring up the menu and click home. This finishes B and C and opens A which in the manifest is set as a singletask.

This all works perfectly, but when I try to open B from A again I have to click twice on the button that starts B. Whereas when the app first opens I have to click only the once to open B

Why could this be like this?

I think I know why. I think B is not finishing when I go from C to A. This is the code running on C

```
    Intent Intent = new Intent(this, com.home.test.Home.class);
    this.setResult(1, Intent);
    startActivity(Intent);
    this.finish();
```

And it should trigger this on B if I am correct

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `singleTask`, in all likelihood. In C, when you call `startActivity()`, pass `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as the `Intent` flags. That will finish C and B en route to starting A.

Comment: Ah I saw this just after my edit and it sounds just like what I need. Could you elaborate a little more if possible. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This is a much better solution to what I had before. I was having trouble implementing it, but it's because I had forgotten to remove the singleTask from the manifest.